# tengo este error Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "DBPRUEBA" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

estoy intentando conectar mi base de datos en Entity Framework por medio de este comando:
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(local); DataBase=DBPRUEBA;Integrated Security=true" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutPutDir DataContext

no sé que tengo mal :( ayuda